# Can any recursive definition be rewritten using foldr?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

Say I have a general recursive definition in haskell like this:

```
foo a0 a1 ... = base_case
foo b0 b1 ...          
    | cond1 = recursive_case_1
    | cond2 = recursive_case_2
    ...
```

Can it always rewritten using foldr? Can it be proved?

Comment: Trivially: `foo a0 a1 ... = const foldr base_case`. More helpfully: not all recursion operates on lists. The shared theme of these two comments is that you should be careful about what you mean when you say "rewritten using `foldr`".

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, `const base_case foldr`?

Comment: @user3237465 Yes, of course. Silly me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we interpret your question literally, we can write `const value foldr` to achieve any `value`, as @DanielWagner pointed out in a comment.

A more interesting question is whether we can instead forbid general recursion from Haskell, and "recurse" *only* through the eliminators/catamorphisms associated to each user-defined data type, which are the natural generalization of `foldr` to inductively defined data types. This is, essentially, (higher-order) primitive recursion.

When this restriction is performed, we can only compose *terminating* functions (the eliminators) together. This means that we can no longer define non terminating functions.

As a first example, we lose the trivial recursion

```
f x = f x
-- or even
a = a
```

since, as said, the language becomes total.

More interestingly, the general fixed point operator is lost.

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f (fix f)
```

A more intriguing question is: what about the *total* functions we can express in Haskell? We do lose all the non-total functions, but do we lose any of the total ones?

Computability theory states that, since the language becomes total (no more non termination), we lose expressiveness even on the total fragment.

The proof is a standard diagonalization argument. Fix any enumeration of programs in the total fragment so that we can speak of "the `i`-th program".
Then, let `eval i x` be the result of running the `i`-th program on the natural `x` as input (for simplicity, assume this is well typed, and that the result is a natural). Note that, since the language is total, then a result *must* exist. Moreover, `eval` can be implemented in the unrestricted Haskell language, since we can write an interpreter of Haskell in Haskell (left as an exercise :-P), and that would work as fine for the fragment. Then, we simply take

```
f n = succ $ eval n n
```

The above is a total function (a composition of total functions) which can be expressed in Haskell, but not in the fragment. Indeed, otherwise there would be a program to compute it, say the `i`-th program. In such case we would have

```
eval i x = f x
```

for all `x`. But then,

```
eval i i = f i = succ $ eval i i
```

which is impossible -- contradiction. QED.

Comment: Isn't it a proof of the fact that we can't enumerate total functions? We first assume that there is a way, but then construct a total function, which is not in the enumeration.

Comment: @user3237465 You can enumerate functions in the language fragment: just take any valid program in the fragment (those who do not use recursion -- you can check for that in a program) and order it by length, and then by string comparison. This provides an effective infinite list. You are right that the last total function is not in the enumeration, meaning it's not in the language fragment.

Comment: Still confused. So the language fragment contains all primitive recursive functions and only them, right? But then why should `f` be in the language fragment? It's defined in terms of `eval` and enumeration stuff — is it primitive recursive? Thanks for the explanations anyway.

Comment: @user3237465 `f` is not in the fragment, that's what we prove! `f` is an example of a total function which is Haskell-definable (since it is computable), but does not belong to the fragment. Essentially, primitive recursion can not craft `f`.

Comment: Note that (as you implied) this is primitive recursion + higher order functions, which, although total, is *much* more powerful than primitive recursion alone. E.g. you can easily write the Ackermann function.

Comment: So your proof is about the fact that primitive recursive functions form a strict subset of total functions. But your original wording is somewhat unfortunate then: "Computability theory states that, since the language becomes total (no more non termination), we lose expressiveness even on the total fragment". It's not that clear from the context, that "total" in the first case means "only primitive recursive functions". Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user3237465 What I meant is: if you somehow restrict Haskell to a language where termination is guaranteed, and the sublanguage can be enumerated (as usually is), then the sublanguage can not express all the total functions Haskell can. In other words: if you want to (effectively) restrict a language to ensure termination, you have to throw away some total functions as well.

Answer (score 4):

In type theory, it is indeed the case that you can *elaborate* all definitions by dependent *pattern-matching* into ones only using *eliminators* (a more strongly-typed version of `fold`s, the generalisation of lists' `foldr`).

See e.g. [Eliminating Dependent Pattern Matching (pdf)](http://strictlypositive.org/goguen.pdf)

Comment: All that do not require the axiom K. And you will need to rewrite some functions (like Berry’s `majority`) in sequential form.

Comment: Yes, and the equations will only hold propositionally, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What equations? Just usual function definitions? For complicated theories (like HoTT) — yes, but for good old ITT eliminators are generated natively (like with Epigram) and everything holds definitionally.